# Upload Files(from the internet) to a dropbox or google drive

Tags: firefox, internet, dropbox, upload, google-drive

I want to download a file from the internet and I have to store it on my dropbox/google drive. Is there a way to skip my PC.

So the dropbox server is downloading the file right in my folder?

This would speed things up a bit.

Thanks

PS: I am using Firefox and Chrome

Answer (score 1):

Your dropbox/google drive is connected to your PC and not generally to the internet. Unless the site you download it from offers a direct upload to dropdox/google drivee you will need to use your PC as an in between.

There is a google [extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/save-to-google-drive/gmbmikajjgmnabiglmofipeabaddhgne) that lets you save screenshots directly to google drive but not one for downloads.

Answer (score 1):

there is a cloud service named [Ballloon](http://ballloon.com/) (with triple L) that let you save links,images... directly on your google drive or Dropbox. also they have a nice and neat chrome extension.

for more info read this article from [lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com/ballloon-saves-online-images-and-documents-to-dropbox-1593852489).

Answer (score 0):

If i remember correctly both google drive and dropbox let you install a folder on your computer associate with your drive/dropbox account, so when you put a file in that folder it syncs automatically to your cloud.

here are  links with a guide to help you install the folders:
Google Drive: https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2374989?hl=en
Dropbox: https://www.dropbox.com/install

After you installed one of these go to your chrome/firefox configuration and under "downloads" chose the download path to one of these folders.
Now whenever you download something it will go directly to the drive/dropbox folder and it will sync automatically to you cloud.

I hope i could help.

Answer (score -3):

I think you can use this website " uploadcloud.net " for download a file from the internet and transfer it to the dropbox or google drive. also you can use the chrome plugin for this matter. 
plugin name : Save to Google Drive
link : http://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/save-to-google-drive/gmbmikajjgmnabiglmofipeabaddhgne?hl=en
Source: http://mydownload.me